# Override "Add to Cart" text

Tags: magento2, addtocart

How can I replace the "Add to Cart" text (In some cases the action also) depending on a custom product attribute?

Comment: Could you explain better your question? Maybe provide an example, so will be easier to understand and answer you.

Comment: Sure.
I have a product with a custom attribute of "publish_date".  I need to be able to change the "Add to Cart" button from "Add to Cart" to "Pre-Order" depending on the publish_date.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not to sure what you require as the information you have was vague.

First call your publish_date like so

```
$publish_date_start = $_product->getData('publish_date_start');

$publish_date_end = $_product->getData('publish_date_end');
```

You can modify this to your needs for example the start date could be current_date and publish_date the end or vice versa.

Then show the pre order text

```
if (Mage::app()->getLocale()->isStoreDateInInterval($store, $publish_date_start, $publish_date_end)) { 
echo $this->__('Pre Order');
}
else{
echo $this->__('Add To Cart');
}
```

Im on my phone so can't test this but you get my idea.

Let me know if this is not what you mean.

Comment: I typed up a thoughtful response but this one is pretty good. I would add that you should wrap your echo statements in `$__()` translation functions so that any theme translations can be overridden with various translation functionality.

Comment: Edited, thank you.

Comment: Nice answer, I would also add the path for the file that need to be modified in order to display the "Add to Cart" or "Pre Order" label: `app/design/frontend/YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

Comment: Is the best way changing a template file?
I would like to be able to have this as a module that will effect any template being used.